# Session is expired in the S3ObjectManager + AppSync + Okta

Tags: android, amazon-s3, okta, aws-appsync

I'm using Okta for login flow, after successful login, we will get the awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey, sessionToken. And next are the below steps to initialize the AWSAppSyncClient

```
// Creating the SessionCredentials and preparing the AmazonS3Client
BasicSessionCredentials sessionCredentials = new BasicSessionCredentials(data.getS3Credentials().accessKeyId(), data.getS3Credentials().secretAccessKey(), data.getS3Credentials().sessionToken());
AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(sessionCredentials); 
amazonS3Client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2));

OidcAuthProvider oidcAuthProvider = oktaAppAuth::getAccessToken;
    AWSAppSyncClient.Builder builder = AWSAppSyncClient.builder()
            .context(context)
            .awsConfiguration(new AWSConfiguration(context))
            .oidcAuthProvider(oidcAuthProvider);
    // Adding the S3ObjectManager Implementation to the AppSyncClient
    builder.s3ObjectManager(new S3ObjectManagerImplementation(amazonS3Client));
    AWSAppSyncClient mAWSAppSyncClient = builder.build();
```

Now, I could able to run the mutations, but while uploading the S3, I'm getting the below error. Somehow I figured out that S3 is caching the old token even after re-login and even when i relaunch the app.

AppSync mutations are working fine

Error:

`Received error response: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The provided token has expired. (Service: null; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ExpiredToken;`